# conditions on 1 array at multiple combined index locations saved to object

Tags: java, arrays

If this is my int array

```
 anArray[0] = 10;
 anArray[1] = 10;
 anArray[2] = 1;
 anArray[3] = 0;
 anArray[4] = 0;
 anArray[5] = 1;
```

How to i search the array for two locations that meet a condition.
I want to search the following index combinations to see if they both contain >=1.

```
0 and 1     
0 and 2    
0 and 3    
0 and 4    
0 and 5    
1 and 2   
1 and 3   
1 and 4   
1 and 5  
2 and 3
2 and 4    
2 and 5   
etc...
```

If the condition is met then i want to save the indexes of the pair of locations meeting the condition to an object.

The only way i can think of doing is to enter the index locations as parameters to the method but their must be a more efficient way.

Comment: are you using javascript?

Comment: -----using java

Answer (score 2):

```
int max = anArray.length;

for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    for (int k = i + 1; k < max; k++) {
        if (anArray[i] >= 1 && anArray[k] >= 1) {
            /* Do something */
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what 'set the indexes to an object' means. But here's a solution to find all combinations of indices that satisfy your conditions:

```
IntStream.range(0, array.length)
    .filter(i -> array[i] >= 1)
    .forEach(i -> IntStream.range(i + 1, array.length)
        .filter(j -> array[j] >= 1)
        .forEach(j -> ...);
```